# Sharepoint 2010 alerts removed overnight

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-alerts

In SharePoint 2010 if someone sets up alerts on a SharePoint site they send a confirmation email to the user but overnight they are deleted at some point. I have disabled and enabled the immediate alerts job in SharePoint but that did nothing. has this happen to anyone else and if so how did you resolve the issue?

Edit: The alerts were setup in the alert menu not notification.

Comment: can you clarify what get's deleted? and how were the alerts setup? via the alert menu or via workflows?